Nginx multiple proxy - need to transfer referer
I have a frontend proxy that forwards requests to a backend proxy.
The frontend proxy is accessible by different urls via https.
I would like to keep the parameter of the initial url which was used to reach the frontend proxy, in order to be able to base conditions on the backend proxy, I admit I am a little lost in the management of the header...
I would therefore like to be able to base different proxy_passes on the backend machine based on the referer condition, if I can transfer this information from the frontend proxy to the backend.
Currently I'm fetching $host on the frontend.
location / {
        limit_req zone=flood burst=12 delay=8;
        if ($block_ua) {
            return 403;
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Referer $host;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass https://proxies;
    }

Can you help me on how to get $host on the backend proxy to use it in if condition to choose proxy_pass redirect?
